# modify the contentType of a file input in a form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, ajaxform

I have the following html code of a form for submitting file to the server:

```
<form id="myform" action="upload_file.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="desc">Description:</label>
<input type="text" name="desc" id\"desc"><br />
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When no file is selected to upload, I have checked in google chrome that the Content-Type of the file is missing. In contrast, it is "application/octet-stream" when we are doing the normal form submission with html.

I wonder how can I modify the Content-Type value so that both cases are consistent. Thank you very much. :)

Belle

I would like to modify the contentType of the file to be submit

Answer (score 0):

As enctype="multipart/form-data" seperating file into binary chunks 
No matter what kind of file it is, an application/octet-stream attachment is rarely viewable in an email, Usenet, or web client,server side .
A MIME attachment with the content type "application/octet-stream" means binary file.
you should get content type of your file in server side

```
 file.getContentType()
```